# MySql Error on adding a category from admin area

Tags: mysql, position

MYSQL ERROR

> Error:    Unknown column 'T1.Field_ID' in 'on clause'

Query:

```
SELECT `T2`.`ID`, `T2`.`Key`, `T2`.`Type` 
FROM `fl_listing_relations` AS `T1` 
RIGHT JOIN `fl_listing_fields` AS `T2` ON `T1`.`Field_ID` = `T2`.`ID` 
WHERE `T1`.`Category_ID` = '42' ORDER BY `T1`.`Position`
```

Function:   getAll
Class:  rlDb

Comment: Add error number in your question, it will really help us to know your problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess the field `Field_ID` in table `fl_listing_relations` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check fl_listing_relations table carefully, Field_ID may be missing